# Error when trying to create a facetgrid of pointplots

Tags: pandas, dataframe, facet, seaborn

I have sequencing data of micro-RNAs (miR) under different conditions ('Comparisons'), and I want to create a point-plot which will show me on different graphs the fold-change for each miR. the data looks like this (and is a pandas data_frame)

```
      mir_Names                    Comparison   Fold_Change
9   9 mmu-miR-100-4373160\n15 m...  YAD-YC  508539.390000
15  9 mmu-miR-100-4373160\n15 m...  YAD-YC  26.816000
17  9 mmu-miR-100-4373160\n15 m...  YAD-YC  728.608000
18  9 mmu-miR-100-4373160\n15 m...  YAD-YC  11483029.706000
```

'upregulated' is a subset of the dataframe and i tried to visualize it using:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(upregulated, col='Comparison', sharex=True, sharey=True,     size=0.75, aspect=12./8, despine=True, margin_titles=True)
g.map(sns.pointplot, 'mir_Names', 'Fold_Change', data=upregulated)
```

**

- but it gives me the error which I couldn't find any solution to it:

**

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-180-a1cf1b282869> in <module>()
      1 g = sns.FacetGrid(upregulated, col='Comparison', sharex=True, sharey=True, size=0.75, aspect=12./8, despine=True, margin_titles=True)
----> 2 g.map(sns.pointplot, 'mir_Names', 'Fold_Change', data=upregulated) #maybe with .count

c:\pyzo2014a\lib\site-packages\seaborn\axisgrid.py in map(self, func,
*args, **kwargs)
    446 
    447         # Finalize the annotations and layout
--> 448         self._finalize_grid(args[:2])
    449 
    450         return self

c:\pyzo2014a\lib\site-packages\seaborn\axisgrid.py in
_finalize_grid(self, axlabels)
    537         self.set_axis_labels(*axlabels)
    538         self.set_titles()
--> 539         self.fig.tight_layout()
    540 
    541     def facet_axis(self, row_i, col_j):

c:\pyzo2014a\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py in tight_layout(self, renderer, pad, h_pad, w_pad, rect)    1663          rect=rect)    1664 
-> 1665         self.subplots_adjust(**kwargs)    1666     1667 

c:\pyzo2014a\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py in subplots_adjust(self, *args, **kwargs)    1520     1521         """
-> 1522         self.subplotpars.update(*args, **kwargs)    1523         for ax in self.axes:    1524             if not isinstance(ax, SubplotBase):

c:\pyzo2014a\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py in update(self, left, bottom, right, top, wspace, hspace)
    223             if self.bottom >= self.top:
    224                 reset()
--> 225                 raise ValueError('bottom cannot be >= top')
    226 
    227     def _update_this(self, s, val):

**ValueError: bottom cannot be >= top**
```

What causes this error?

Comment: Can you include a small sample of your "unregulated" data frame that reproduces the error?

Comment: Are the `mir_Names` values super long? Does this happen when you aren't drawing such tiny facets?

Comment: print(upregulated.head(), end='\n \n \n')
print(type(upregulated), end='\n')
print(len(upregulated), end='\n')

Comment: mir_Names Comparison   Fold_Change                                                               
                                                                                                           1182     mmu-miR-147-4395373   YAD-VOAD  3.135551e+10
1177  mmu-miR-142-5p-4395359   YAD-VOAD  2.454993e+10
311   mmu-miR-770-3p-4395564     YAD-YC  8.081635e+09
334      mmu-miR-99b-4373007     YAD-YC  3.697749e+09
1465     mmu-miR-99b-4373007   YAD-VOAD  3.539749e+09
 
 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
288                                                Thanks!!

Comment: Don't include that information in the comments! It's completely illegible. Edit your question if you want to proved more information.